# Android Shadow on Bent Layout

Tags: android, layout, shadow

I have a layout like this:

[image]

The bottom view is just a framelayout, with a vector drawable with the shape of a rectangle with a short side, so there is an empty space there that is invisible.The grey shadow is what i want to achieve. I have shadow drawable in my app which i use for the bottom of some layouts (which are not bent like this now).

So my question is, is there a way of accomplishing that? Idk maybe rotating an horizontal shadow drawable resource, or like using a normal horizontal shadow, then rotate it to the right angle, and set use `setX()` to the right position. Need some advices on this, would preferebly want a layer-list with my vector drawable and a shadow below, but i have never done this. Is this possiblE?

EDIT:Vector Drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="500dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportWidth="500"
    android:viewportHeight="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M 0 0 L 500 0 L 500 65 L 0 100 L 0 0 Z" />
</vector>
```

PS. The vector is rotated 45º x and y in code

Comment: Can you post your vector drawable code?

Comment: sure updated the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue by implementing a [View Outline Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) in the View i wanted to display the custom shadow.

Then i created a convexPath `outline.setConvexPath` in the method `getOutline` with the desired path do draw the shadow. Works flawlessly.